# Should I append the armarture before binding it to the mesh?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Should I append the armarture before binding it to the mesh?

I know you should append the mesh before binding but does that apply to the rig as well?

Answer (score 0):

if you **want to join** armatures, do it before binding meshes to them (because many problems occur after joining armatures)

but if you want to have a mesh to be affected by multiple armatures and you **don't want to join** them just :

1. take care of names of bones to be unique in either armature
2. set an armature modifier for each of your armatures